# Confused about XML DOM object

Tags: javascript, xml, dom, xmlhttprequest

I am using the below JavaScript to try to get a node name from an xml document.

```
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    xhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xhttp.open("GET", "doc.xml", false);
xhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xhttp.responseXML;
alert(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DesignPatterns")[0].childNodes[0].nodeName);
}
```

The XML document...

```
<DesignPatterns>
     <Composite>Composite</Composite>
</DesignPatterns>
```

The Alert is outputting '#text'. I expected it to output 'Composite'. Why is this happening, is there some invisible and magical #text node that I am not seeing? I assume its the /n that I see in debug but this just makes no sense to me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of the formatting characters (whitespace, newline etc) in your formatted xml. Everything is treated as a node. Any continuous white space becomes a text node. You could use [children](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode.children) instead of childNodes. children will not include text nodes.

```
xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DesignPatterns")[0].children[0].nodeName
```

Comment: works just like you said, but I'm curious why this will not work? xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DesignPatterns")[0].children[0].nodeValue

Comment: @Shijima For that you should do `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DesignPatterns")[0].children[0].firstChild.nodeValue` or use

Comment: Understood, I didn't realize that 'Composite' is considered its own Node, and thought it was part of <Composite> so figured I could access the text with nodeValue. Thanks for your help!